# Adding extra information to createGroup( ) for use in discoveryPeers( )

Tags: android, android-intent, android-networking, wifi-direct

Do you know if there's a way to add extra information during the createGroup() of WifiP2pManager ? I would like other app that invoke discoveryPeers to obtain some extra info such as Group Name, location, etc.

I'm trying to display on a List the groups owner, but I need more info before estabilishing a connection to have a nice interface (user chosen group name, icon, etc).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way. You just simply add a local service with the information you want to advertise.

Then with clients, you just do service discovery after the peer discovery phase.